# AWS EMR step doesn't find jar imported from s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am attempting to run a spark application on aws emr in client mode.  I have setup a bootstrap action to import needed files and the jar from s3, and I have a step to run a single spark job.

However when the step executes, the jar I have imported isn't found.  Here is the stderr output:

> 19/12/01 13:42:05 WARN DependencyUtils: Local jar /mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/s-2HLX7KPZCA07B/~/myApplicationDirectory does not exist, skipping.

I am able to successfully import the jar and other needed files for the application from my s3 bucket to the master instance, I simply import them to `home/ec2-user/myApplicationDirectory/myJar.jar` via a bootstrap action.

However I don't understand why the step is looking for the jar at mnt/var/lib/hadoop/...etc.

here are the relevant parts of the cli configuration:

```
--steps '[{"Args":["spark-submit",
"--deploy-mode","client",
"--num-executors","1",
“--driver-java-options","-Xss4M",
"--conf","spark.driver.maxResultSize=20g",
"--class”,”myApplicationClass”,
“~/myApplicationDirectory”,
“myJar.jar",
…
   application specific arguments and paths to folders here 
…],
”Type":"CUSTOM_JAR",
```

thanks for any help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it doesn't understand the `~` as referring to the home directory.  Try changing `"~/myApplicationDirectory"` to `"/home/ec2-user/myApplicationDirectory"`.

---

<sup>A little warning: in the sample in your question, straight quotation marks `"` are mixed with "smart" ones `“`.  Make sure the "smart" quotation marks don't end up in your configuration file, or you will get very confusing error messages.</sup>